# SQL Puzzle - Why can't I join these two subqueries?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I'm stuck on a SQL query.

Consider the following table:

```
Table DG_GAME_ROUNDS    
RoundId int
GameId  int
RoundNumber int
Value   varchar(20)
Guess   varchar(20)
Answer  varchar(20)
Correct bit
Minutes int
Seconds int
Milliseconds    int
```

This table holds the results of game rounds. Now sometimes you can fat finger an answer to the game and wind up with a guess time of 35 or even 0 milliseconds. These answers skew the results of my game and I want to remove them.

I want to figure out the average guess time where the guess is at least 200 milliseconds long. So if a game had five rounds with guesses of 455, 400, 340, 30, 300. I want to ignore the 30 and average out the remaining four values and get an average guess time of 374. Without dropping the 30 the average guess time would be 305.

My problem is that I'm trying to join two subqueries and I'm getting an error message that there is a problem around the "on" statement. I think joining subqueries is allowed.

```
 select vt.gameid, vt.totalms, vt.numofguesses, vt.correctguesses
from
(select    gr.gameid 
       ,  sum((gr.seconds*1000) + gr.milliseconds) as totalms
       ,  count(gr.roundid) as numofguesses
       ,  sum(cast(gr.correct as int)) as correctguesses
          from work_tables.dbo.dg_game_rounds gr (nolock)            
          group by gr.gameid 
  ) vt 
inner join  (
              select vtIII.gameid, vtIII.avgtime
              from 
                  (
                     select vtII.gameid, sum(vtII.avgms)/count(vtII.avgms) as avgtime
                     from (
                              select gr.gameid, gr.seconds * 1000 + gr.milliseconds as avgms
                              from dg_game_rounds gr (nolock)
                              where gr.seconds * 1000 + gr.milliseconds > 200
                          ) vtII
                     group by vtII.gameid
                   ) vtIII 
 on vtIII.gameid = vt.gameid
```

Comment: Have you considered creating views to make your T-SQL code a little easier to read/write/maintain? If this query is called a lot, an indexed view might even make sense for the subquery you've called vt.

Comment: Voting to close since questions like this are pretty much guaranteed not to ever help anyone else in the future.  This is way too localized to be of future use.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're missing an ending ) (2nd to last line)

```
select vt.gameid, vt.totalms, vt.numofguesses, vt.correctguesses
from
(select    gr.gameid 
       ,  sum((gr.seconds*1000) + gr.milliseconds) as totalms
       ,  count(gr.roundid) as numofguesses
       ,  sum(cast(gr.correct as int)) as correctguesses
          from work_tables.dbo.dg_game_rounds gr (nolock)            
          group by gr.gameid 
  ) vt 
inner join  (
              select vtIII.gameid, vtIII.avgtime
              from 
                  (
                     select vtII.gameid, sum(vtII.avgms)/count(vtII.avgms) as avgtime
                     from (
                              select gr.gameid, gr.seconds * 1000 + gr.milliseconds as avgms
                              from dg_game_rounds gr (nolock)
                              where gr.seconds * 1000 + gr.milliseconds > 200
                          ) vtII
                     group by vtII.gameid
                   ) vtIII ) vtIII
 on vtIII.gameid = vt.gameid
```

Answer (score 4):

You haven't closed all your subqueries:

```
select vt.gameid, vt.totalms, vt.numofguesses, vt.correctguesses
from
(select    gr.gameid 
       ,  sum((gr.seconds*1000) + gr.milliseconds) as totalms
       ,  count(gr.roundid) as numofguesses
       ,  sum(cast(gr.correct as int)) as correctguesses
          from work_tables.dbo.dg_game_rounds gr (nolock)            
          group by gr.gameid 
  ) vt 
inner join  (
              select vtIII.gameid, vtIII.avgtime
              from 
                  (
                     select vtII.gameid, sum(vtII.avgms)/count(vtII.avgms) as avgtime
                     from (
                              select gr.gameid, gr.seconds * 1000 + gr.milliseconds as avgms
                              from dg_game_rounds gr (nolock)
                              where gr.seconds * 1000 + gr.milliseconds > 200
                          ) vtII
                     group by vtII.gameid
                   ) vtIII ) f
 on f.gameid = vt.gameid
```

I added this: `) vtIII ) f`

Answer (score 1):

Count your parentheses.

```
inner join  (
```

is never closed.